# Node + Firestore is causing heap out of memory with a basic query

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I've been experimenting with Firebase's Firestore databse with NodeJS.

I have a basic express.js backend that runs everything, and everytime I try to query a doc from the database I get:
`FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

Here's my code:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const credentials = require('./firebase_private.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(credentials)
});

const db = admin.firestore();

const subRef = db.collection("subscribers");
console.log('Checking if token exists');
const existingToken = await subRef.doc('123').get(); // <-- This line causes the error
```

My local setup:

- Node version 18
- firebase-admin verison 11.5.0
- An empty Firestore db, with only one small document just for testing

Things I've tried:

- Reinstalling all npm modules by deleting `npm_modules` folder and running `npm i`
- Switching back and forth between node 12 and node 18
- Changing the heap size with `--max_old_space_size=4096`
- Querying the data online from Firebase's dashboard

Comment: If you can open a `node` REPL and run the above code *without* getting that error then the problem lies somewhere else within your Express app, and we would need more information about the app and how this particular piece of code is called to understand what the problem is.

Comment: @CodeMonster, did the previous comment address your concern?